# Why is the input cutting the border of the div?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a visual-only freight calculation area for a school project. But the input is taking the edge off the div as I change the font size of the input and the button.

```css
.box-cep {
  width            : 245px;
  height           : 30px;
  margin-top       : 10px;
  margin-left      : 25px;
  border           : 2px solid black;
  }
.box-cep input {
  width            : 150px;
  height           : 30px;
  border           : none;
  }
.box-cep button {
  width            : 90px;
  height           : 30px;
  border           : none;
  background-color : #FF7518;
  color            : white;
  font-family      : "Century Gothic";
  font-size        : 18px;
  font-weight      : bold;
  }
.cep-txt {
  font-family      : "Century Gothic";
  font-size        : 14px;
  padding-left     : 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box-cep">
  <label for="">
    <input type="text" class="cep-txt" placeholder="Digite seu CEP...">
    <button>Calcular!</button>
    </label>
</div>
```

[image: Printscreen]

Comment: NOt the actual problem but you should not have both a `button` and `input` inside the one `label` element : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Answer (score 1):

It's happened because you have set the box-cep height, and the height of the input is overflow the container. For alternately, you can use max-content height for box-cep. And to make the button horizontaly with the input, you can make the box-cep flex and place the button outside the label. Here is my example, i hope it can help you.

```css
.box-cep {
  width            : 245px;
  height           : fit-content;
  margin-top       : 10px;
  margin-left      : 25px;
  border           : 2px solid black;
  display          : flex;
  align-items      : center;
  }
.box-cep input {
  width            : 150px;
  height           : 30px;
  border           : none;
  }
.box-cep button {
  width            : 90px;
  height           : 32px;
  border           : none;
  background-color : #FF7518;
  color            : white;
  font-family      : "Century Gothic";
  font-size        : 18px;
  font-weight      : bold;
  }
.cep-txt {
  font-family      : "Century Gothic";
  font-size        : 14px;
  padding-left     : 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box-cep">
  <label for="">
    <input type="text" class="cep-txt" placeholder="Digite seu CEP...">
  </label>
  <button>Calcular!</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it happens because you add `height : 30px` in class .box-cep,
if you give `height : 100%` then it will be normal, and remove height in class `.box-cep button`

like the example below

```css
.box-cep {
  width            : 245px;
  height           : 100%;
  margin-top       : 10px;
  margin-left      : 25px;
  border           : 2px solid black;
  display          : flex;
  align-items       : "center";
  }
.box-cep input {
  width            : 150px;
  height           : 30px;
  border           : none;
  }
.box-cep button {
  width            : 90px;
  border           : none;
  background-color : #FF7518;
  color            : white;
  font-family      : "Century Gothic";
  font-size        : 18px;
  font-weight      : bold;
  }
.cep-txt {
  font-family      : "Century Gothic";
  font-size        : 14px;
  padding-left     : 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="box-cep">
  <input type="text" name="input" class="cep-txt" placeholder="Digite seu CEP...">
  
  <button>Calcular!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: height: full; is not a valid CSS value!

Comment: Also align-items: "center"; It doesn't need quotation marks.

Comment: sorry i mean height 100%

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:relative` and `height:100%` to get the full width inside the container.

```
.box-cep {
  width            : 245px;
  height           : 30px;
  margin-top       : 10px;
  margin-left      : 25px;
  border           : 2px solid black;
  }
.box-cep input {
  width            : 150px;
  height           : 100%; // Replace 30px with 100%
  position         : relative; // Add position: relative
  border           : none;
  }
.box-cep button {
  width            : 90px;
  height           : 100%; // Here Same, Replace 30px with 100%
  position         : relative; // Add position: relative here too
  border           : none;
  background-color : #FF7518;
  color            : white;
  font-family      : "Century Gothic";
  font-size        : 18px;
  font-weight      : bold;
  }
.cep-txt {
  font-family      : "Century Gothic";
  font-size        : 14px;
  padding-left     : 5px;
  }
```

Then the button and the input will have the same height. Also add `overflow:hidden` to the `.box-cep` div to prevent its contents from overflowing.